# What kind of a date format is this? 437432903.96807599067687988281

Tags: date, format

Somehow `437432903.96807599067687988281` translates to `November 11, 2014, 4:08pm`, but I'm not sure how.

Edit: The context is I'm trying to export data from [Thyme](http://resume.joaomoreno.com/thyme/), a menubar timer for Mac. It's recorded in an XML file called `storedata`. For example:

```
<object type="SESSION" id="z102">
    <attribute name="seconds" type="int32">43</attribute>
    <attribute name="minutes" type="int32">10</attribute>
    <attribute name="hours" type="int32">4</attribute>
    <attribute name="date" type="date">437432903.96807599067687988281</attribute>
</object>
```

Comment: Looks like [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) ?

Comment: That was my first thought too, but the timestamp right now in Unix is 1416233031. This translates to 1983.

Comment: Huh. Except oddly enough, it translates to November 11th, 1983, at 21:08 GMT. So it has the day right, and the time sort-of right, but the year's off by 31. Strange... I wonder what the rationale there is.

Comment: Something about that rings a bell - I think "classic" Mac OS (pre OS X) used time stamps based on a different start date than Unix, maybe 1980 ?

Comment: Ahh, that's interesting!

Comment: I guess you can assume it's a time in seconds then - it's just the baseline date/time that is non-standard. (BTW looks like I was wrong about "classic" Mac OS - that used 1 Jan 1904, apparently).

Comment: Apple has (or had) a time format based on number of seconds since 2001. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFTimeUtils/index.html

Comment: Aha ! Apparently Cocoa uses an epoch of January 1, 2001 - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple's OS X Objective C application framework Cocoa has a date/time class [NSDate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/index.html) which uses an epoch date of January 1st 2001. So a timestamp of 437432903.96807599067687988281 seconds, when added to January 1st 2001, gives you the correct date and time: [9:08:23 pm GMT  |  Tuesday, November 11, 2014](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=January+1st+2001+%2B+437432903.96807599067687988281+seconds)